# Convert gettext po file to php array

Tags: php, arrays, gettext

I have built a site for a client and I used gettext for translation. I have written two custom function for echo and text retrieval from po files. Currently, when I update my php file, I update my po file from poedit software. I have input custom functions in poedit settings (**() and _**() ) and then poedit scans all php files and generate po files for me.

What I need is a software or utility that can scan my php files and generate translation file in a php array.

There are too many PHP files and I do not want to manually update translation file. I have already checked po2php.

Answer (score -1):

**PowerGrep**

You could use [Powergrep](http://www.powergrep.com/). You can search trough files by regex. Then export the matches to an file snf import them to your translation software.

[image]

**Agent Ransack**

An free alternative is software called [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/). It support exporting and searching with rexeg.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me costly. Is there any other software you can recommend me?

Comment: 5 years ago I worked with software called `agent ransack` http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/ . It seems still to exists but dont know if its supports exporting results

Comment: Notepad++ might work for you, it has a "find in files" function that uses RegExps ... but aren't .po files compiled?

Comment: I see it has an export function.